# в словаре находятся несколько словарей и надо вывести одинаковые значения в питоне как сдлеать

Tags: python, json, dict

есть файл с json (https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=A) и нужно вывести из всех словарей значение по ключу strDrink, но я как бы не знаю сколько раз он повторяется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем библиотеку requests для обработки

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=A'
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)

for item in data['drinks']:
    print(item['strDrink'])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Хорошо, буду более подробно объяснять)Хотя тут код на пару строк не вижу ничего сложного

Comment: `JSON` можно получить прямо из запроса, отдельную не надо библиотеку дёргать: `data = response.json()`